# git tagging `HEAD` or branches

Tags: git

Assume I have a git repository where the current `HEAD` points to commit `abc123`, which is the newest commit in `myBranch`.

When I create a tag, pointing at `HEAD` (or alternatively `myBranch`), will that tag point to

a) the commit `abc123`, which will always be the same?

b) `HEAD` (or alternatively `myBranch`), which can vary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always the commit `abc123`.

In most cases, a tag points to a commit. If `abc123` is the very commit that you want to tag, then `git tag tag_foo abc123`. If `HEAD` happens to point to `abc123`, then `git tag tag_foo HEAD` is equivalent. Later, even if `HEAD` gets to point to another commit, `tag_foo` still points at `abc123`.

Comment: Thank you. :-) You say "In most cases" – in which cases does it point to something different than a commit?

Comment: @Bowi Git has four kinds of objects, which are commits, trees, blobs and annotated tags. A lightweight tag or an annotated tag can point to any of these objects.

Comment: Okay, I understand. :-)